# Handling asyncronous function in a loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following code :

```
async def async_function():
    await some_function()


# TODO : Doesn't work
def sync_function():
    for i in range (100):
        async_function()
```

In the past I had no loop in `sync_function`, so I managed to call `async_function` using `asyncio.run()`. Now that I have a this for loop, I don't find the proper way to handle my asynchronous function.

The current code throws the following warning

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'async_function' was never awaited
```

And part of the logic in it is not done during runtime.

What would be the good way to do this ?

Comment: You can move the loop to an async function and `await` the `async_function` (recommended) or you can call `asyncio.run` as before but in the loop (should work but isn't efficient).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asyncio tasks` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html).
This is a working example:

```py
import asyncio


async def async_function(i):
    """ dummy code """
    print("Hi from", i) 
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


def sync_function():
    for i in range(100):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # get asyncio loop
        loop.create_task(async_function(i))  # schedule task

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather())  # run the asyncio.gather function, who's role is to run all scheduled tasks.


sync_function()
```